# static member declared const but initialized as constexpr

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, constexpr

consider a class with a constant member:

```
class foo {
public:
    const static int N;
};
```

`foo::N` needs to initialized:

```
constexpr int foo::N = 5;
```

and note how using the `constexpr` qualifier instead of `const` here seems like a mistake.

but GCC, Clang and MSVC all compile just fine!

- is there something in the language that allows changing qualifiers here?
- is it an error overlooked by all three compilers?

---

Clang even allows both qualifier versions simultaneously:

```
constexpr int foo::N = 3;
const int foo::N = 5;

int main(){
    return foo::N; //returns 3
}
```

what's going on?

Comment: That will only work for integral types, I reckon

Comment: Had a [very quick] look in the standard, and nothing jumps out. This actually smells kind of buggy to me, but it wouldn't surprise me if it were a loophole or even a feature; such is C++ these days. Good question.

Comment: `constexpr int foo::N = 3;` So `N`ìs initialized in the compilation time

Answer (score 2):

Since obviously the value of a variable that has been declared but not defined cannot be used in a constant expression, `constexpr` pertains only to the **definition** of a variable.  (Of course, if the variable is inline, perhaps because of being a static member declared `constexpr`, *every* definition must have `constexpr`.)  It implies `const` (on the variable itself: `constexpr char*` is `char *const`, not `const char*`), so you haven’t changed the variable’s **type**.  This is no different from

```
// foo.hpp
extern const int x;

// foo.cpp
constexpr int x=2;
```

which is perhaps less surprising.

So everything is fine!  The variable’s value can be used in constant expressions only in the **translation unit** that contains the definition, but that’s no surprise, and could easily be construed as a feature for **modularity**.  Clang is buggy to allow two definitions: presumably it’s trying to ignore the (deprecated, as of C++17) out-of-class definition for a constexpr static data member defined in the class.